# setting the background color on a view dynamically

Tags: android

i an trying to refactor some code that sets the background color of a View using the Android Color class rather than my own custom Color class. everything seems to load up and run on the activity ok, but when i change the value of the spinner the background color of the View doesn't change. what am i missing?

```
package com.example.android.colorpickerii;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class ColorPickerActivity extends Activity {

static final int MIN_VAL = 0;
static final int MAX_VAL = 255;
View colorView;
int alpha = 255, red = 164, green = 199, blue = 57;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_picker);

    setupAlphaPicker();
    setupRedPicker();
    setupGreenPicker();
    setupBluePicker();

    setupColorView();

}

private void setupColorView() {
    colorView = findViewById(R.id.color_box);
    colorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(getAlpha(),
                                            getRed(),
                                            getGreen(),
                                            getBlue()));
}

private void setupBluePicker() {
    NumberPicker bluePicker;
    bluePicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.bluePicker);
    bluePicker.setMinValue(MIN_VAL);
    bluePicker.setMaxValue(MAX_VAL);
    bluePicker.setValue(57);

    bluePicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            setBlue(newVal);
        }
    });

}

private void setupGreenPicker() {
    NumberPicker greenPicker;
    greenPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.greenPicker);
    greenPicker.setMinValue(MIN_VAL);
    greenPicker.setMaxValue(MAX_VAL);
    greenPicker.setValue(199);

    greenPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            setGreen(newVal);
        }
    });
}

private void setupRedPicker() {
    NumberPicker redPicker;
    redPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.redPicker);
    redPicker.setMinValue(MIN_VAL);
    redPicker.setMaxValue(MAX_VAL);
    redPicker.setValue(164);

    redPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            setRed(newVal);
        }
    });

}

private void setupAlphaPicker() {
    NumberPicker alphaPicker;
    alphaPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.alphaPicker);
    alphaPicker.setMinValue(MIN_VAL);
    alphaPicker.setMaxValue(MAX_VAL);
    alphaPicker.setValue(255);

    alphaPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            setAlpha(newVal);
        }
    });

}

private void setAlpha(int newVal) { this.alpha = newVal; }
private void setRed(int newVal) { this.red = newVal; }
private void setGreen(int newVal) { this.green = newVal; }
private void setBlue(int newVal) { this.blue = newVal; }

private int getAlpha() { return this.alpha; }
private int getRed() {  return this.red; }
private int getGreen() { return this.green; }
private int getBlue() { return this.blue; }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently only setting the color of the background once with your call to `setupColorView()` in `onCreate`.

In the `onValueChange` method for each of your `NumberPickers` you call one of your `setXxx` methods, which just save the value into a class level variable, but then you are not doing anything with it.
After any change to one of these variables, you should then apply the new values to the background.

For example:

```
...
private void setAlpha(int newValue) {
    this.alpha = newVal;
    setupColorView()
}

private void setRed(int newValue) {
    this.red = newVal;
    setupColorView()
}

private void setGreen(int newValue) {
    this.green = newVal;
    setupColorView()
}

private void setBlue(int newValue) {
    this.blue = newVal;
    setupColorView()
}
...
```